# RestKit: sending 2 x nested array as GET parameters, incorrect serialization

Tags: ios, restkit

I'm trying to send an array of points in GET request via RestKit:

```
{
 coordinates: [
  [50,60],
  [100,200],
  [300,400]
 ]
}
```

Code:

```
[restkitManager getObjectsAtPath:path parameters:coordinates success:... failure:...]
```

When I check my server's log I see that this request was sent to the server:

```
http://<...>?coordinates[][]=50&coordinates[][]=60&coordinates[][]=100...
```

Which is incorrect and I get broken array at the server. Numbers must be present between brackets [0]..[1]..:

```
http://<...>?coordinates[0][0]=50&coordinates[0][1]=60&coordinates[1][0]=100...
```

Is it a bug? If so, is there any workaround? I'm already thinking about creating a dictionary with numbers as keys.

**SO, MY SOLUTION**

I converted root NSArray to NSDictionary with numbers as keys. Now I can send it via GET request with RestKit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you really want is to POST to the server. Using GET will encode the parameters into the URL as query parameters. Technically you can send body data with a GET but it isn't used much.

Be sure what your server is expecting and:

1. Try POSTing to the server
2. Ensure that you're setting the serialisation type to JSON

If you do want to use a GET and query parameters, your better option is to convert the array contents into whatever string format the server expects and supply that in the dictionary as the value for the `coordinates` key.

Comment: Hi again and thanks for the answer :) It is a search (filtering) request which is usually being made via GET (even in Google you can see search params in URL). I'll try to convert it to POST but still don't understand why RestKit can't do it via GET? Or may be it's Objective-C native serialization methods which RestKit use. JavaScript does it just fine.